# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Worldbuilding's [3rd moderator election](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Monty Wild] [image: L.Dutch]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5724087510892544/0).

Comment: Welcome to janitorial duty.  Your coveralls and name tags are in moderator chat.  You must provide your own mop or broom. :)

Comment: @James, don't be a meanie; you can at least let them know they can fill their buckets at the communal spigot. :-)

Comment: Congratulations!  Really was a two-way battle for third..!

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to our new moderators and thank you to *everybody* who stood in this election.  Go look at the summary report; that was a crazy fight to the finish!  We had a strong pool of candidates.

Answer (score 13):

Thank you all for entrusting me. I will do my best.

Comment: Just do what you have been doing until now. ;) But now you got a shiny mod diamond to accompany you!

Comment: What ArtificialSoul said! Congratulations and all the best to you L.Dutch!

Answer (score 12):

Please join in giving our new moderators a very warm welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that was very close (not surprising given the excellent candidates I suppose).

Congratulations to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

An amazing election! Looking at the election results it was fascinating to see how things played out. Congratulations to our new moderators. Well done. This was an excellent set of candidates. So commiserations to those who didn't win a place, and should there be another election, at some future time, I hope they will stand again.

The best of luck with your new responsibilities and have fun with it all.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats to the winners and also thanks to those who put there names forward but were unsuccessful this time - appreciate your willingness to try and serve the community.